# Storing object as a column in LINQ

Tags: database, linq, class, object, store

i have some class which constructs itself from string, like this:

```
CurrencyVector v = new CurrencyVector("10 WMR / 20 WMZ");
```

It's actually a class which holds multiple currency values, but it does not matter much.

I need to change type of column in my LINQ table (in vs 2010 designer) from String to that class, CurrencyVector.

If i do it - i get runtime error when LINQ runtime tries to cast String as CurrencyVector (when populating the table from database).
Adding IConvertible did not help.

I wrapped these columns in properties, but it's ugly and slow solution.
Searching internet gave no results.

Comment: I assume that you are using LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Do you have control over the DB schema? Is the DB in SQL Server 2005 or 2008? If your answer to both questions is "yes", then have you considered using a .NET managed UDT for the DB column? See this SO answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935315/return-clr-sql-server-udt-from-sql-server-to-client-app

Answer (score 0):

You can always extend the class and create another property that returns the object. Like so (pseudo code)

```
public partial class MyLinqEntity {
   public CurrencyVector  CurrencyVector {
       get {
          return new CurrencyVector(this.ColumnHoldingCurrencyVector);
       }
   }

}
```

where CurrencyVector has the logic to convert the string in the constructor.